# Adding space on HTML code is changing layout

Tags: html, css

The question title may not be the best, as I couldn't figure out how to word this.

I made a quick website with webflow, and once I exported the code I'm finding a strange problem. I can't figure out what the problem may be.

When the HTML code is compressed, the layout is good, but when you format it (indenting, spacing, etc), the layout changes.

Here is the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoWqVN

I have included the whole code. As you can see, the navigation bar is rendering in one line, as it should be. However, if you try formatting the html (tidy it here), it will add some padding around each of the navbar elements.

If you add space after each of the links

```
<a class="w-inline-block navigation-section primero"><div class="navigation-text">En 2D</div></a>
```

It renders a space in the bar, pushing the rest to the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block` elements such as in your navigation have spacing between them when the code for them is not one continuous line. This formatting is unpleasant though. In your example I would just add:

```
.w-inline-block {
  float: left;
}
```

[Article on subject.](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

```css
.w-inline-block {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html data-wf-site="560fb42cfb4cea064e6a9703" data-wf-page="560fb42cfb4cea064e6a9704">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>guerrarte</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="generator" content="Webflow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/560fb42cfb4cea064e6a9703/css/guerrarte.webflow.5a2acd60c.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
    <script>
      WebFont.load({
        google: {
        families: ["Ubuntu:300,300italic,400,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic","Merriweather:300,400,700,900"]
        }
      });  
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/0globals/modernizr-2.7.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/img/webclip.png">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="body-wrapper">
    <div class="w-section w-clearfix website-header">
      <div class="header-containerimage">
        <div class="header-manolin-image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-container-text">
        <div class="header-manolin-text">Manuel Dominguez Guerra</div>
        <div class="header-text-descripcion">
          Aenean pulvinar semper finibus. Donec faucibus quam arcu, quis tincidunt mauris viverra quis. Duis rutrum convallis velit ac imperdiet. Aliquam luctus nulla quis feugiat dignissim. Aliquam iaculis in eros id fermentum.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-section navigation-bar">
      <a class="w-inline-block navigation-section primero">
        <div class="navigation-text">En 2D</div>
      </a>
      <a class="w-inline-block navigation-section segundo" href="#">
        <div class="navigation-text">En 3D</div>
      </a>
      <a class="w-inline-block navigation-section tercero" href="#">
        <div class="navigation-text">Pinceladas</div>
      </a>
      <a class="w-inline-block navigation-section cuarto" href="#">
        <div class="navigation-text">Blog</div>
      </a>
      <a class="w-inline-block navigation-section quinto" href="#">
        <div class="navigation-text">Biografía</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <footer class="w-section footer">
      <a class="w-inline-block" href="mailto:arte@guerrarte.com">
        <div class="footer-text">arte@guerrarte.com</div>
      </a>
    </footer>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/560fb42cfb4cea064e6a9703/js/webflow.972a0ffa2.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 9]><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour. A line break in the source code will be be rendered as a space in HTML.

Example that will insert a space between the two `<div />`:

```
<div>
  Content
</div>
<div>
  Other content
</div>
```

In order to avoid this, you can either minify your HTML or use the following syntax:

```
<div>
  Content
</div
><div>
  Other content
</div>
```

Comment: drop use the following syntax?

Comment: This is the correct answer, additionally, this is a nice article explaining the various methods to avoid spaces in your html (and more) https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/